# Conditional where on join 3 tables

Tags: mysql

There is 4 tables on my db.

```
posts
- id
- user_id(FK to users)

comments
- id
- post_id(FK to posts)
- user_id(FK to users)
- body

users
- id

reports
- id
- comment_id(FK to comments)
- reported_user_id(FK to users)
- report_user_id(FK to users)
```

And mock data is here.

```
mysql> select * from users;
+----+
| id |
+----+
|  1 |
|  2 |
|  3 |
|  4 |
+----+

mysql> select * from posts;
+----+---------+
| id | user_id |
+----+---------+
|  1 |       1 |
+----+---------+

mysql> select * from comments;
+----+---------+----------+----------+
| id | user_id | post_id  | body     |
+----+---------+----------+----------+
|  1 |       2 |        1 | user 2   |
|  2 |       2 |        1 | user 2-2 |
|  3 |       3 |        1 | user 3   |
|  4 |       3 |        1 | user 3-2 |
+----+---------+----------+----------+

mysql> select * from reports;
+----+------------+------------------+----------------+
| id | comment_id | reported_user_id | report_user_id |
+----+------------+------------------+----------------+
|  1 |          2 |                2 |              3 |
|  2 |          3 |                3 |              1 |
+----+------------+------------------+----------------+
```

My goal is shows different results for each user.

Please refer below conditions.

1. If comment is reported by `post owner`, it only appear when `comment owner` is request.
2. If comment is reported by `other user(not post owner)`, it only hide who `report comment`.

As you know that, `comments.id = 2` is reported by post owner, so it will be hide all users except comment owner.

Also `comments.id = 3` is reported by other user, is only hide for user who report comment.

**Expected result**

When user 2 request comments

```
+----+---------+----------+----------+
| id | user_id | post_id  | body     |
+----+---------+----------+----------+
|  1 |       2 |        1 | user 2   |
|  2 |       2 |        1 | user 2-2 |
|  4 |       3 |        1 | user 3-2 |
+----+---------+----------+----------+
```

When user 3 request comments

```
+----+---------+----------+----------+
| id | user_id | post_id  | body     |
+----+---------+----------+----------+
|  1 |       2 |        1 | user 2   |
|  3 |       3 |        1 | user 3   |
|  4 |       3 |        1 | user 3-2 |
+----+---------+----------+----------+
```

When user 1 request comments

```
+----+---------+----------+----------+
| id | user_id | post_id  | body     |
+----+---------+----------+----------+
|  1 |       2 |        1 | user 2   |
|  3 |       3 |        1 | user 3   |
|  4 |       3 |        1 | user 3-2 |
+----+---------+----------+----------+
```

Is it possible extract these results with a query?

Thanks.

Comment: Why using tag PostgreSQL if this question is about MySQL?

Comment: @Cid Because mysql and postgresql is very similar.

Comment: *"Because mysql and postgresql is very similar"* Not at all. Please use proper tags.

Comment: There is a missing relation between `posts` and `comments`.

Comment: @Cid I updated my posts.